# intellij Idea with Ideavim Unable to type

Tags: linux, vim, freeze, intellij-idea, typing

I'm currently using Intellij IDEA with IdeaVim. Sometimes when I type the type screen freezes (like you do in vim with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> is not working. When i restart IntelliJ idea it works again...

I searched on web but there is always someone asking *do you use IdeaVim?* but they do not say what to do if the answer is yes. There should be a better way than restarting. Thank you...

Using Ubuntu (GNU Linux)
Intellij Idea 16

Comment: What OS do you use ?

Comment: @AntonDozortsev Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known bugs:

- [Editors stop responding to keyboard input, must restart IntellIJ](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-23472)
- [Keyboard input sometimes is blocked when IBus is active](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-78860)

And someone found a [workaround](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-23472#comment=27-1025813). Add below line a the top of the `idea.sh` file:

> export XMODIFIERS=""

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Mine was caused by IBUS links were enough to solve the problem, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off **Vim Emulator** from **Tools** in the **intelliJ**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[This workaround](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-23472#focus=Comments-27-4130750.0-0) seems help

In top menu -> **Help** -> **Edit Custom VM Options...**

add this 2 lines at bottom

```
-Drecreate.x11.input.method=true
-Dawt.ime.disabled=true
```

then restart IDE

P/S: My environment: Ubuntu 20.04, PhpStorm 2019.1